# How do I make a fixed position child div wrap inside a parent div with a fixed width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap a fixed position child element within a parent div without it breaking out of the div.

I would like it to behave like the div that is not fixed but I need the child element to be fixed and automatically wrap or resize because I am going to be needing it for a responsive site. So this is why I don't really want to do an overflow situation if possible as I will be having right aligned content in the fixed div

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">I am a child div with a 100% width</div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-unfixed">I am a child div that is unfixed (this is the desired affect I am   after but using a fixed position if possible)</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
   background:green;
   padding:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   margin-right:100px;
   width:200px
}

.child {
   background:yellow;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   text-align:right;
}
.child-unfixed {
   background:pink;
}
```

[Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/tLbggwp8/)

Comment: remove the max-width of the parent div?

Comment: Fixed positions are similar to absolute. They will need a top;left;right;bottom. That might not be what you are looking for. I would take a look at this article about positions http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Like others have said, the problem with using "fixed" positioning is that it takes the element out of flow. Thus you can't position its parent around it because it's as if it didn't have one.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this and thought I would add a solution that worked for me for anyone that may find this. Instead of making the child position: fixed, I made the parent position: fixed, then made the child position: absolute.

Here's the code that I used: https://codepen.io/redclaycreative/pen/MLeEee

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="parent shadow">
    <h1 class="child">東京からこんにちは</h1>
  <div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #C6312D;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed;` cannot be inside a `div`. It sticks to the window and can´t stick to html elements.

See [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> fixed
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't think there would be a way of doing this because it acts like an absolute div and takes the element of the page.

But it seems that inherit on the width does the trick.

```
width: inherit;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/tLbggwp8/12/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tLbggwp8/11/

Try removing the `position:fixed;` as indicated in another answer, and then setting the `max-width` setting to the difference of the parent div and padding.

Manually I have set this to 460px (20px padding on each side).

A few other things you can work with to help with the layout:

- Use of the `calc` [max-width:calc(x-y);] function to calculate the `max-width` for more dynamic use
- `box-sizing:border-box;` to assist with the true size of the area with padding and margin contained within the final calculation of size

Answer (score 0):

You can add `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` to the **parent** of that element and it will works fine.